# Wordpress Tablepress border around a column

Tags: css, wordpress, html-table, css-tables

I use the Tablepress plugin for Wordpress and I made a border around one column. Here is how I made it:

`.tablepress-id-1 .column-2{border-left:solid 4px #fb9901;
border-right:solid 4px #fb9901;}
.tablepress-id-1 .row-10 .column-2{border-bottom:solid 4px #fb9901;}
.tablepress-id-1 .row-1 .column-2{border-top:solid 4px #fb9901;}`

It looks like I wanted it, but I have the feeling that there is a way to make is smarter and leaner. (I need to replicate it on many other tables)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using css custom property for the color:

```
.tablepress {
  --border-color: fb9001;
}
.tablepress-id-1 .column-2 {
  border-left: 4px solid var(--border-color);
}
```